# QObject class info absent from debug symbols (edit but other Qt classes are present)

Tags: c++, qt, gdb

I'm building a Qt project using g++ and debugging with gdb. Recently, I noticed that class info about `QObject` and all Qt types that derive from it, seem to be absent from my debug symbols. For example, the gdb command `ptype QObject` results in `No symbol "QObject" in current context.` Similarly I can't call methods, examine the `d_ptr` of an instance, or downcast a derived pointer to `QObject*` inside the debugger. `info types` does not list any contents from qobject.h.

For derived classes of `QObject` defined in my own code, I can see my own members just fine but where the base class is listed, it just says `<QObject> = {<No data fields>}`

Other Qt classes that are declared in public headers, for example `QString`, are present in the debug symbols. I can't see anything about the declaration of `QObject` that would make it different.

I've got a minimalist project that I've been using to examine this problem:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>

int main()
{
    QObject* spiff = new QObject();

    spiff->setObjectName("Foo");
    std::cout << qPrintable(spiff->objectName()) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
#project.pro
QT -= gui
CONFIG += debug
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Nothing here seems squirrely to me. There are no build errors, and the code executes quite as expected.

This seems to be unaffected by debug level or optimization flags, any debug symbol format, whether I use g++ vs. clang++ or gdb vs lldb, distro (tried on Arch, Ubuntu, and minGW-w64), or whether pretty-printing is enabled.

I've had a hard time finding any info about gdb's features for examining classes (which makes sense: why would you use a debugger to examine static code) but since this is preventing me from calling methods, it's a major inconvenience. Nothing I've found seems to indicate a reason only some classes would be omitted from debug symbols, or what could be peculiar to Qt about this.

Edit: I had mistakenly believed I was linking against a version of Qt that had debug symbols when I was actually still using the release build. Now, the debugger does recognize `QObject`, but the question still remains to me of why is QObject different in this regard from other Qt classes like `QString` and `QVariant`?

Comment: It occurs to me this probably has to do with the vtable. Not positive what the specifics would be, but that would be a concrete difference between QObject and the other classes (which I'm pretty sure have no virtual functions), as well as having something to do with linkage

Answer (score 1):

### Qt libraries don't ship with debug symbols

Qt libraries are built-in release, and don't have debug symbols. When building your application in Debug, only your application's code has debug symbols, but you still link to the same Qt libraries. This means you need to build Qt libraries with Debug symbols!

Build Qt from source takes some time, but will let you debug or step-in Qt (and QObject) code. Note that Meta object code `moc`ed from your classes (from `moc_<yourclass>.cpp` files) can be debugged without a needing a debug version of Qt, because this is compiled as part of your application.

When building Qt, you can add the `-force-debug-info` flag when invoking `configure` command to add debug symbols. If using Qt Creator, you will then have to add this new version of Qt in Qt Creator, and create a new kit for it.

- The official documentation to build Qt from sources can be found at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html
- You can also have a look at the QObject class implementation only, conveniently hosted there: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html

Comment: I apologize for the rude tone of my previous comment. I had made a mistake previously and hadn't actually linked against the library with debug symbols. Having fixed that, `QObject` is there now just like I should expect. This doesn't make sense to me though, as I should expect a class definition in a header not to require debug symbols from a linked library -- and other Qt classes do not exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Oh just realized I miss read your question, I thought you were trying to step in Qt code for some reason. I agree that you should be able to access public data from Qt classes. Qt classes are using d_ptr to preserve the ABI though, and I wouldn't expect it to be inspectable from gdb, though I think I remember looking at its content form regular Qt build... QObject is part of Qt Core lib but so is QString. Is that possible that gdb is somewhat getting confused by the presence (or lack of) moc_ files in its context?